# jQuery dataTables header is not adjusting to column values initially, but adjusting after I drag the screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datatables

I am developing a responsive webpage, where I use function to dynamically generate Data tables from the server side response.

Here is the code in **Util.js** which is used to generate datatables.

```
function setDataTableData(id, data) {
  var tHead, tBody;
  tHead = "<thead><tr>";
  tBody = "<tbody>";
  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data[0]).length; i++) {
    tHead = tHead + "<td>" + Object.keys(data[0])[i] + "</td>";
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tBody = tBody + "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(data[i]).length; j++) {
      tBody = tBody + "<td>" + data[i][Object.keys(data[i])[j]] + "</td>";
    }
  }
  tHead = tHead + "</tr></thead>";
  tBody = tBody + "</tr></tbody>";
  console.log(tHead + tBody);
  $(id).html(tHead + tBody);
  var table = $(id).dataTable({
    scrollY: "200px",
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
    bFilter: true
  });
  $(id).on("keyup", ".ui-input-text", function() {
    table.search(this.value).draw();
  });
}
```

In **Index.html** I have included the js libraries as below

```
<script src="./cordova.js"></script>
<script src="./js/vendor/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/vendor/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/vendor/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="./js/vendor/less.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/vendor/Bootdatepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/events.js"></script>
<script src="./js/util.js"></script>
<script src="./js/template.js"></script>
<script src="./js/function.js"></script>
```

I have used datatables js and css from the [official datatables](https://www.datatables.net/blog/2015-04-30) website

**This is screen shot of how my page is displaying**

[image: screen shot when page loaded]

Interestingly the header part is adjusting automatically if I drag or adjust the screen.

The default search field which is there in pic is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

I can [**reproduce your code**](http://jsfiddle.net/w7u2wkys/) but not replicate the behavior. I would use `<th></th>` in `<thead>` instead of `<td>`'s though.

However, I am pretty sure a [**`columns.adjust()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()) will solve your problem. After all, this is what happens after dragging the screen anyway.

```
var table = $(id).dataTable({
  "scrollY": "200px",
  "scrollCollapse": true,
  "paging": false,
  "bFilter": true
}).DataTable().columns.adjust();
```